# Response Json data convert to customize model object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

String result = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", String.class);

CurrentPrice currentPrice = objectMapper.readValue(result, CurrentPrice.class);

System.out.println(currentPrice.toString());
```

CurrentPrice.class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CurrentPrice {

    private String disclaimer;

    private String chartName;

    private Time time;

    private CurrentDetail bpi;

}
```

Time.class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Time {

    private String updated;

    private String updatedISO;

    private String updateduk;

}
```

CurrentDetali.class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CurrentDetail {

    private CurrentInfo USD;

    private CurrentInfo GBP;

    private CurrentInfo EUR;

}
```

CurrentInfo.class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CurrentInfo {

    private String code;

    private String symbol;

    private String rate;

    private String description;

    private BigDecimal rate_float;

}
```

CurrentPrice(Current result is not my expect)

```text
CurrentPrice(disclaimer=This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org, chartName=Bitcoin, time=Time(updated=Oct 26, 2022 09:15:00 UTC, updatedISO=2022-10-26T09:15:00+00:00, updateduk=Oct 26, 2022 at 10:15 BST), bpi=CurrentDetail(USD=null, GBP=null, EUR=null))
```

I want API Data converter to CurrentPrice is
CurrentPrice(disclaimer=This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org, chartName=Bitcoin, time=Time(updated=Oct 26, 2022 09:15:00 UTC, updatedISO=2022-10-26T09:15:00+00:00, updateduk=Oct 26, 2022 at 10:15 BST), bpi=CurrentDetail(USD=CurrentInfo(code=USD,symbol=$,rate=20,229.4096,description=United States Dollar,rate_float=20229.4096), CurrentDetail(USD=CurrentInfo(code=GBP,symbol=$,rate=20,229.4096,description=British Pound Sterling,rate_float=20229.4096), CurrentInfo(code=GBP,symbol=$,rate=20,229.4096,description=British Pound Sterling,rate_float=20229.4096)))

Comment: Hi& Welcome! Why not/tried:  `CurrentPrice currentPrice = restTemplate.getForObject("...", CurrentPrice.class);`? (Without "string crutch")

Comment: Have you tried adding @JsonUnwrapped to private CurrentInfo USD; This is because this is a nested part under the parent class. example : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonunwrapped.htm

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.